# How to call apex:component (vfc) inside aura component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, aura, visualforce-component

Can we call visualforce component inside Aura component? If yes, can you share the syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. They are completely different technologies. You would need to create a Visualforce page, then display that in an `iframe`.

Comment: Thankyou for answering

Comment: @VasuGupta You have any syntax for this?

Comment: @user3214361 It's just `<iframe src="/apex/PageName"></iframe>`, along with any styles you need.

Comment: @sfdcfox `wallmart.vfc` is my component name trying this ````<iframe src="/apex/wallmart"></iframe>```` showing nothing. Note: this is a community page

Comment: @user3214361 That will make a difference. If you haven't already, ask a new question; I'll probably need more space than a comment box to help you out here.

Comment: I created New question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/416915/how-to-call-visualforce-component-wallmart-vfc-inside-aura-component