# How to call Visualforce Component (wallmart.vfc) inside aura component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, aura, visualforce-component

I there any way that we can call the Visualforce component inside the Aura component?

I tried the below code its not working, Can anyone help me on this?

```
<!-- MyAuraComponent.cmp -->
<aura:component>
    <apex:include component="wallmart" />
</aura:component>
```

Edited

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `apex` namespace doesn't work in Aura. Inside a community, in the Builder, you can just click on Components, then add a Visualforce component, and specify the page in the component configuration. There's no need to write a custom component.

However, if you still wanted this approach, you'd want to use something like:

```
<iframe src="/communityprefix/apex/wallmart">
</iframe>
```

You need to make sure that the Guest User has access (Setup | User Interface | Sites and Domains | Sites |  | Public Access Settings | Visualforce Pages), and make sure that the page allows itself to be framed.

Comment: Getting An unexpected connection error occurred. screenshot attached above